# hibernate over http

Tags: hibernate, jdbc

I have a requirement to persist java objects in a database and retrieve it using an eclipse rcp application. Is there a way to achieve this using hibernate without jdbc and over http ? rcp clients are in distributed environment and firewall could be an issue. Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build two sorts of applications

- Clients based on rcp
- Server based on hibernate.

The communication between client and server could be based on http using techniques like

- REST
- SOAP
- own format
- JSON
- and very much more

Comment: Thanks. I was looking more of a wrapper implementation over http to avoid firewall.